# Saving PNG from Google POST request

Tags: php, stream

I have a simple bit of code that outputs the stream from a google post request as a PNG. It's for using google to create a QRcode. What I want to do though is save this as a PNG file on my server and I can't seem to figure out how to go about it as I'm not so familiar with working with streams. Here's the code:

```
<?php

    //This script will generate the slug ID and create a QRCode by requesting it from Google Chart API
    header('content-type: image/png');

    $url = 'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?';
    $chs = 'chs=150x150';
    $cht = 'cht=qr';
    $chl = 'chl='.urlencode('Hello World!');

    $qstring = $url ."&". $chs ."&". $cht ."&". $chl;       

    // Send the request, and print out the returned bytes.
    $context = stream_context_create(
        array('http' => array(
            'method' => 'POST',
            'content' => $qstring
    )));
    fpassthru(fopen($url, 'r', false, $context));

?>
```

Comment: Does it have to be a post? The generated url works fine as a simple GET request, which means you could just use `echo file_get_contents(...)` instead.

Comment: It can be a get request, but still, I'm unsure how I would save it. http://code.google.com/apis/chart/infographics/docs/overview.html

Comment: `file_put_contents('qr.png', file_get_contents(...));` fpassthru() is for sending output directly to the client. For your code, you'd want fwrite() instead, on a file handle opened previously.

Comment: Ahh ok I've got it working! Much easier! I was trying to get the stream into string and was really having a hard time wrestling it. Doing the simple URL get request worked. I'll post the code as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way, based on your code and specified 'save this as a PNG file on my server':

```
<?php
$url = 'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?';
$chs = 'chs=150x150';
$cht = 'cht=qr';
$chl = 'chl='.urlencode('Hello World!');

$qstring = $url ."&". $chs ."&". $cht ."&". $chl;       

$data = file_get_contents($qstring);

$f = fopen('file.png', 'w');
fwrite($f, $data);
fclose($f);
```

Add error checking etc. to taste.

Comment: kindly let me know how can i create qr code with logo

Comment: Hi Daren, its working nicely. But how can i add my logo center of this barcode image. any idea please share

Answer (score 1):

To write the result to a file, use fwrite() instead of fpassthru().

You could use file_get_contents() and file_put_contents(), but these require storing the entire image in a string, which could be memory intensive for large images.  It's not an issue here since the qrcode images are small, but it's worth thinking about in general.

You don't really need to create a stream context, since the web service will work fine with an HTTP GET instead of POST.

There is also a function called http_build_query() which you can use to simplify building the URL.

```
<?php

$url = 'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?' . http_build_query(array(
    'chs' => '150x150',
    'cht' => 'qr',
    'chl' => 'Hello World!'
));

$src = fopen($url, 'rb');
$dst = fopen('file.png', 'w');
while (!feof($src)) {
    fwrite($dst, fread($src, 1024));
}

?>
```